# TensorFlow does not recognize two "equal" tensor shapes as equal

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compare two tensor shapes for equality like so:

```
 assert tf.TensorShape([None]) == tf.TensorShape([None])
```

To my surprise this assertion currently fails. Should it not succeed or am I making wrong assumptions here?

I am running TensorFlow 1.5.0-dev20171206 (from tf-nightly) and Python 3.6.3 on macOS.

Comment: The assumption is wrong actually. When you specify `None`, it means that the number of dimensions can be any. So, it doesn't make sense to compare two shapes which can be of any size

Comment: @Nain Yes, of course! Thank you. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: Sure. I have updated this in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is wrong actually. When you specify None, it means that the number of dimensions can be any. So, it doesn't make sense to compare two shapes which can be of any size. In order to gain a fine understanding on how it works, you can look at the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape)